# Magento - Retrieve specific XML Debug File

Tags: php, magento, debugging

I have got a problem with a debug option inside magento.
First of all I tried to ignore all the debug string with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEBUG);
```

inside `index.php` but without success, so I have installed firegento to take a deeper look(and still try to hide the lines).
 Now inside the `system.log` file I have got this kind of lines:

```
USER AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
FILE: shop/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php:511
<config/>
```

So I tried to take a look at that file and this is line 511:

```
if(!$xml){ Mage::log($string); }
```

that is part of  `public function loadString`.
I wonder if there is a possibility to show which file throw that debug line

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on one of your config xml files, localized in a "etc/" directory of modules.

You can check formatting with a xml validator online tool. Try to remember what is the last installed module or changes have you made and parse your xml file.

Typically, it's a error of missing tag.

I hope this is helpful